# Is it possible to query like this?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

**Code**

```
class Member{
         string name          
        }



  class Group{
      string name
      static hasMany = [member: Member]
}
```

**//CONTROLLER**

```
def member = Member.get(1)               // I get member object as expected
def group = Group.findByMember(member)   //ERROR
```

**Question**

it is not possible to find a group like this.... (since group and member is in one to many relationship)

is there any other simple way?

**Solution is here:**

http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html

Comment: what error are you getting?  Does `Member.get(1)` return an Object as you would expect?

Comment: nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: Solution is here:

http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution is here:**

```
def group = Group.withCriteria {
    createAlias("member", "m")
    eq("m.id", 1)
}
```

**SOURCE**

http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html

Comment: External linking is a bit gray area since who knows, maybe that blog will disappear or something. Please include at least a summary of the solution to your post.